# Unable to refresh data on the view. using factor, angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am able to get the info on the first call but on closing the alert $scope.closeDialog I do go to the server and fetch the data but my model vm.info is not getting updated on the view. ... the alert is on a different tab than where vm.info is... ( if that makes any difference )  any ideas?

Inside factory

```
    dataFactory.getInfo= function(from, to) {
    return $http({
           url: urlBase + 'GetInfo',
           method: "GET",
           params: { from: from, to: to }
       });
    }
```

I have Have a function within an alert that closes dialog.

```
        $scope.closeDialog = function () {
            $mdDialog.hide();
            vm.info(vm.from, vm.to);
            //window.location.reload();
        };
```

in my controller:

```
    vm = this;
    vm.info= function getInformation(from, to) {
    dataFactory.getInfo(from, to)
        .success(function (data) {
                vm.info = data;
        })
        .error(function (error) {
                vm.status = 'Unable to load data: ' + error.message;
        });
    }
```

the only solution is to use windows.location.reload(). But to just refresh one item on my screen I have to refresh the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are overriding the function `getInformation` with `data` on `success`, which is why it only works once.

In your controller:

```
vm = this;

vm.info;

vm.getInfo = function(from, to) {
dataFactory.getInfo(from, to)
    .success(function (data) {
            vm.info = data;
    })
    .error(function (error) {
            vm.status = 'Unable to load data: ' + error.message;
    });
}
```

Comment: It does not work. it only updates items on current tab and not other tabs.

Comment: I found the issue. the problem was that for each tab I had on top a div that was referencing my controller. Just FYI.